# Synapse XPath Variables reference

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have installed WSO2 EI 6.1.1. I have created an http proxy and I am creating a sequence that obtains certain values from the request and processes it through a Java Class mediator. I have succesfully obtained the parameters from the URL in a property mediator by defining the expresion as `$url:token`.

I am trying to obtain also the http method (Get, Post, Put...) and the body of the request but I cannot find the correct XPath variables that define them.

This is an example of a request I want to capture (I want PUT and the JSON data)

```
PUT path?token=aaaa HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 28
Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
Content-Type: application/json

{
"id": 14,
"value": "+02"
}
```

It seems that the values are realted to the $trp and $body objects, but I have not been able to find any reference on how to obtain them.

---

UPDATE:

Defining $body as the expresion gives me the following content:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
```

Comment: Do you realize that XPath is for selecting nodes within XML?

Comment: I am not really sure how I can get to that data. As I understand the values I am searching are in XML format in the data exchanged in the request.

Comment: Documentation describes some xpath variables, as $trp and $body (transport anjd body) that are supposed to contain the data, but I have not been able to extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these.

Body:

```
<property name="payload" expression="$body"/>
```

HTTP Verb:

```
<property name="verb" expression="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD"/>
```

or

```
<property name="verb" expression="$ctx:HTTP_METHOD"/>
```

Comment: It works for the Method (axis, not the last one) but when requesting the body I only get <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>. No trace of the json content in the request

Comment: The Body can be fully obtained in the Java Class mediator using: reqBody = context.getEnvelope().getBody().toString();